# Need a suggestion with CodeContracts

Tags: c#, validation, code-contracts

Hi guys
I'm new to CC and I need your suggestion. I started with CC in my last project. I have a WCF contract, which should be implemented by third parties. I want to assign code contracts to service contracts. Let's say I have a class Car (Service Contract) and it's OperationContract ICar. ICar has a method GetCar() which as I said above, should be implemented by our clients. I create a code Contract class for Icar and in GetCar method, I validate the contract using CarContractHelper class. I introduced a helper class which validates the Car class the following way: `Contract.Ensure(CarContractHelper.Validate(Contract.Result<Car>()))`. Is this a correct approach to solve the problem? Or is there any better way?
I'm also validating each property member of Car class in it's setters, what do you think about this, is it necessary or it's an overkill?
Thanks
And of course, I will mark the correct answer and vote up :)

UPDATE

---

@StriplingWarrior I introduced the car validation helper to deal with the repetitive contract validation code. for example:

```
Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(car.Id);
Contract.Requires(car.Mileage > 0);
```

etc. Instead of writing everywhere Contract.Requires code, I just have one helper class for each business object which validates the business object's contract. And that's what I want to know, if this is a correct approach or maybe there is a better way?
thanks.

P.S. I'm validating every property in their own setters because invariant method won't work for me (?), as far as I know, invariants works when any method of the class is called, and in my case, wcf contract doesn't have any methods. So I choose to validate inside properties setter. Is it a good approach?

Comment: Can you provide some code? It looks like you're saying `ICar.GetCar()` returns a value of type `Car`, but in that case what does `Car` look like? Does `Car` implement `ICar`?

Comment: Thanks Austin :-) It's updated

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done much with Code Contracts, but here are some observations:

One of the advantages of code contracts is the ability to look at the contract for a particular method and know what's expected. Seeing `CarContractHelper.Validate(Contract.Result<Car>())` doesn't really tell me anything, so I would have to drill down to know that (for example) the return value's `CarId` is greater than zero. So in one way I would rather see `Contract.Ensure(Contract.Result<Car>().CarId > 0)`, and maybe a few other requirements. On the other hand, I can see how this could create a lot of repetitive contract code that would be hard to manage if (for instance) you added a new property to the `Car` class.

Another *potential* advantage of code contracts is the ability to have compile-time checks on your requirements. For example, consider the following code:

```
var car = _carService.GetCar();
_crashTestUtil.TestCar(car);
```

If TestCar's contract requires that `car.CarId > 0`, and `GetCar()` failed to ensure that this was the case, the compiler can warn you about this fact. In order for this to work with a validation helper class I imagine that you'll need to make sure your validation helper class *also* uses code contract methods to do your contract checks.

Even though you are performing checks on the Car class's property setters, I do think it still makes sense to validate that all required values have been set before this method returns.

Comment: Now it's more clear. Vote up & I updated the question :) Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Altough Code Contracts can be used for this, I personally would not use it this way. I think pure validation belongs to the Domain Layer ( provided you're using a somewhat Domain Driven approach) , and the car should be able to be validated with or without Code Contracts.

In my opinion, it would be better if your API handled the invalid car or threw an appropriate exception. If you're using Code Contracts to check the car's validity, you only have 2 options: 1. Car is valid 2. Car is invalid, ContractException ( or your own exception).

I'm pro-Code Contracts, but would rather see the Contracts more verbose. You should definitely try to make the invariant work. An alternative is to define Contracts on your interface.

Comment: Thanks KoMet for your support. Maybe you are right, but I'm dealing with WCF DataContracts and ServiceContracts. ServiceContracts are interfaces, such as GetCar() for example. I can't have a domain layer up to that interface, it should be an interface. And what concerns data contracts, on the required field, CC will throw ArgumentException if the contract is violated. Am I doing it the wrong way? Thanks again

Comment: I'm not very familiar with WCF Data-and ServiceContracts, I'm afraid =) You're not wrong to throw an ArgumentException, I was merely talking about the Validate method not being very verbose about your contracts, and pointing out that there might be scenarios where you want more flexibility than throwing an argumentexception directly =)